# Comparison to -1 or undefined don t work, either with == or ===

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, compare

Here a sample of code:

```
do
{
    line=gets(smil);
    if (line===-1){console.log("Abort");callback(-1);}
    console.log("line= "+line);
}while(line.search("<video")===-1);
```

The first output goes well, but suddenly, I get

```
line= -1
TypeError: Object -1 has no method 'search'
```

gets is a custom function, wich return either a string or -1 in case of error.

I tried with == instead of ===, but it just do the same.

I tried to replace the return -1 of gets by undefined, but I just get

```
line= undefined
TypeError: Cannot call method 'search' of undefined
```

instead.

Why the if don t execute?

EDIT:
Tried with

```
var pline
do
{
    pline=gets(smil);
    if (pline===-1){console.log("Abort");callback(-1);}
    console.log("line= "+pline);
}while(pline.search("<video")===-1);
```

to avoid overriding another variable, got the same result

Comment: I think your condition shold be `}while(line === -1);`

Comment: @limelights: So creating a new variable to avoid the problem?

Comment: @mohkan The goal is to read the file until I find "<video" in it, and exit if I get EOF or another error, I don t think the while is a problem

Comment: If line is invalid, should you not break the loop. The loop condition `line.search("<video")===-1` will throw that error if line is not valid object, does not have search.

Comment: @user568109: I do break the loop, and exit the function, at least, it s what I try to do with the if condition.

Comment: You are calling callback function. Why would it break the loop. You have to do `break;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a two-fer this question.

1st - You're overwriting the variable `line` right after the `do`.
That's why you're getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object -1 has no method 'search'`

Change that line to `parsed_line = gets(smil); //also never forget semicolons`

2nd - `search` isn't a function of String, you want the `indexOf()` function.

So change `while(line.search())` to `while(line.indexOf())`.

I made a fiddle for you that [demonstrates it here](http://jsfiddle.net/EYCgA/)

Answer (score 0):

try adding a break.

```
do
{
    line=gets(smil);
    if (line===-1){
        console.log("Abort");
        callback(-1);
        break;
    }
    console.log("line= "+line);
}while(line.search("<video")===-1);
```